# getJSON only returning a HTMLCollection

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I'm trying to create an email-validity (that is, check against database if email doesn't already exist) function using `getJSON` (sort of like the `jquery.ui.autocomplete`).
However, the data received from the callback seems to be just the site header of the current page, not the page the `InitSource-function` calls to. (This I've checked, and is correctly being called).
Can someone please tell me what is going wrong, why am I getting a `HTMLCollection` and not the correct `JSON`?

This is the code:

```
$.fn.Functions = {
    InitSource: function () {   
        $.getJSON(this.source, { term: this.getTerm() }, this.response(data));
    },  
    onChange: function () {   
        this.InitSource();
    },  
    response: function (data) {   
        alert(data.result);
    },  
    getTerm: function () {   
        var key = $('.' + this.selector).val();
        if (key.length > 0) return key;
    }   
};
```

The `this.source` is a relative path: `/EmailCheck.aspx`.
And returns a single value: `{"result" : "true"}`.

Can someone please tell this rookie why he's getting completely the wrong data in the callback?

Comment: Please ,use Firebug or similar to determine what your browser is sending in the AJAX request, and what you're getting back in the response. If you're still confused, add the request/response to your question.

Comment: The request AND response are completely correct, the request: GET /EmailCheck.aspx?term=test, response: {"result", "true"}.

Comment: Nevermind, @Guffa is correct.

Comment: You're right, but thank you for your swift response and help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the function and then sending the return value to the `getJSON` call. Use the function name without a parameter to send the function reference instead of calling it.

As you are using a method, you need to use `proxy` so that it is called with the context of your object:

```
$.getJSON(this.source, { term: this.getTerm() }, $.proxy(this.response, this));
```

Comment: Working like a dream! Thank you so much!